# gcc undeclared identifier "_asm"

Tags: c++, c, unix, gcc, gdb

I'm trying to understand how memory works, and how every instruction allocates memory. I'm also trying to understand the concept of offset, and base pointers. I am doing this for intel processors and MIPS. I am able to access memory windows in Visual Studio, however when i use gcc and gdb on UNIX, i get the this error on my code
![after compilation code][1]

**error: use of undeclared identifier "_asm"**
   **_asm**

I do not get this error in VISUAL STUDIO
Here's what I'm trying to run 
(Very simple code)

```html
void main()
{
 int quizint = 0x01000080;
 int n = 0xfffffff;
 int MIPSzint = 0x80000001;
 register int m = 3;
 register int p = 256;
 static int q = 0x7fffffff;
 static int r = 0x10000000;
 static int R = 0x8000000;
 _asm
 {
  start_loop:
   mov ebx, MIPSzint
   add ebx, -2
   mov ecx, quizint
   mov eax, n
   sub eax, q
   add eax, R
   mov edx, 1
   add edx, q
   add edx, 1
   add edx, n
   add R, -1
 }
}
```

====>>> **_asm** gives me the error.
Question is, do I need to add something in order to make it work in gcc?

Answer (score 4):

GCC calls it `asm` instead of `_asm` and the syntax is a little different.  See https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html and http://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html

Answer (score 1):

Use `__asm__` if you are compiling with GNU extensions disabled. With GNU extensions you can also use `asm` but `_asm` is not supported by `gcc`.